# Bluetooth "No adaptor found" in 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, blueman

After an update routine, my bluetooth adapter has disappeared

[image]

My ubuntu:
[image]

I'm not an expert in "ppas" and packages... but, may be here the problem?

[image]
[image]

Edited: 'lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb'

```
albert@albert-nuc:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.